# jsf stickyKit not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, sticky

I use [Sticky Kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) in JSF for my left navigation bar to scroll vertically and I need it to recalculate when I execute a ajax-method (which loads extra content to the main area).

first I activate it once in $(document).ready(...):

```
$("#navbar").stick_in_parent()
```

and the recalculation shoule be executed with:

```
$("#navbar").trigger("sticky_kit:recalc")
```

But unfortunately it is not executed (I have put an alert("recalculate") into the recalc) when I call it in my jquery ajax-listener (which is fired)?

(I use the JSF-Ajax-Jquery-Listener, because the default .ajaxComplete() does not work with JSF)

Answer (score 0):

The recalc event only applies to the body element. From the docs:

> Sticky Kit listens to one event on document.body.
>
> sticky_kit:recalc — trigger this event to cause all sticky elements to
>   be recalculated. More information below.

and below:

> You can cause a recalculation to happen by triggering an event on document.body:
>
> $(document.body).trigger("sticky_kit:recalc")

Comment: no, it just ignores the method. the alert("1") before and the alert("2") after are called as usual. it just does not enter the method. can this have something to do that I use it in JSF?

Comment: Maybe, is JSF generating the `<script>` tags in the right order?

Comment: yes, the activation of the sticky Kit works (it follows correctly). just when I want to trigger a recalc manually, it ignores it

Comment: The recalc function is called when the script starts, so if Sticky Kit is working correctly as you say, the alerts would have been shown already. If this is not the case, your alerts might not be in the right place. Or the script you edited is not the one loaded in the browser. I'd have a look at that first.

Comment: I thing you misunderstood my question; the documentation says that I can manualle execute recalc by calling "$(document.body).trigger("sticky_kit:recalc")". the alerts I was talking about are shown before and after this trigger-action. everytime I do an ajax call. just the trigger-action is ignored.

Comment: Well in your question you said you put an alert into the recalc function. Are you sure Sticky Kit is working before the first alert is shown? Because it sounds like the event hasn't been bound yet.

Comment: Hi, yes it works definetly. it still works after calling the trigger. the problem is that it ignores this call (so no triggering is executed). there was never the problem of not working at all

Comment: Thats weird. I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FncE8/) from the example on the website. The recalc link below is working. Maybe you can play around with this fiddle to show when the problem arises.